# How to stop duplicate function definitions in C that are created by macro expansion

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

for example, let's say I have a macro that expands into a struct definition with corresponding functions like so:

`array.h`

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <assert.h>

#define Array(t, size) Array_##t ##_##size

#define define_array(t, size) \
typedef struct Array(t, size) \
{ \
    t data[size]; \
} Array(t, size); \
void array_insert_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, t elm, int index) \
{ \
    assert(index < size); \
    arr->data[index] = elm; \
} \
t array_get_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, int index) \
{ \
    assert(index < size); \
    return arr->data[index]; \
}

#endif
```

and I want to use this in multiple files like so:

`s1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array.h"

define_array(int, 10)

Array(int, 10) get_ints()
{
    Array(int, 10) ret;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        array_insert_int(&ret, i, i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And now I want to use the type and functions that were expanded by `define_array(int, 10)` in other files. So what I did is:

`s2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array.h"

define_array(int, 10)

extern Array(int, 10) get_ints();

int main()
{
    Array(int, 10) arr;
    arr = get_ints();
    
    printf("%d\n", array_get_int(&arr, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

However I get a linking error telling me that I have mutiple definitions of the same functions. And so I thought putting guards around the expansion would help:

`s1.c + s2.c`

```
#ifndef ARRAY_INT_10
#define ARRAY_INT_10
define_array(int, 10)
#endif
```

but I still get the same error for some reason. Why is this error happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: make functions `static`. Anyway, I call it macro perversion in its most hardcore version.

Comment: You're including the same header over and over again in different files. Try including it only in the main file, which should allow for use across the rest of the project.

Comment: `(sizeof(arr->data)/sizeof(t))` is just `size` (except for type).

Comment: Don't define variables or functions in headers. Only declare them there. Try xmacros to still keep all implementation in one place. I recommend the undef-free version.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these macros?  Array definitions like `int array[10];` are clear, easy-to-understand, and easy to use.  These macros hide the definitions, add complexity, and make bugs almost impossible to spot and debug.  What are you trying to do with them that makes that worthwhile?

Comment: @AndrewHenle not exactly the same as `int array[10]` since I can return `Array(int, 10)` directly from functions without managing memory. Either way this is only an example to explain the problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this error happening and how do I fix it?

You may not have more than one definition of the same external identifier in the same program.  You are defining external functions, and by `#include`ing your header in more than one translation unit, you obtain a definition of each associated function in each translation unit, which is not allowed.

The simplest fix would be to modify the macros to declare the functions `static`.  Their identifiers will then be internal (to each translation unit) instead of external.

It would also be possible to arrange to have `array.h` provide only prototypes of the functions, and then to have a separate, single source file for the function implementations.  This would be a lot messier, though, at least because

- you would need a way to determine what functions needed to be implemented in that one source, and
- to avoid name collisions, you would need to incorporate the array sizes into the function names, too, not just into the structure tags and typedef names.

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

- generate `static inline` functions, or
- stop using these macros and implement a more generic system.

Note in particular that the `index` argument should be defined with a type `size_t` to ensure invalid accesses with negative index values are caught.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate macros -- a `declare_array` and a `define_array` macro:

```
#define declare_array(t, size) \
typedef struct Array(t, size) \
{ \
    t data[size]; \
} Array(t, size); \
void array_insert_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, t elm, int index); \
t array_get_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, int index);

#define define_array(t, size) \
declare_array(t, size) \
void array_insert_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, t elm, int index) \
{ \
    assert(index < size); \
    arr->data[index] = elm; \
} \
t array_get_##t(Array(t, size) *arr, int index) \
{ \
    assert(index < size); \
    return arr->data[index]; \
}
```

You can now use `declare_array(int, 10)` in a header file (or generally in mulitple compilation units), and use `define_array(int, 10)` in exactly one compilation unit to get the actual needed definitions.

If you want, you can include `inline` versions of the functions in the `declare_array` macro.

Comment: this is a really good solution as well. Which do you think is better, using static in the functions or doing this? I'm worried that using static will worsen performance as the functions are defined in each unit as a different function, so the binary size might be large. But idk it might be optimized by compiler

Comment: Its a trade-off as you note.  There's also the problem if you have mulitple arrays types with the same element type (and different sizes), as this will try to overload the array_insert/array_get functions, which C does not support (though it would be ok if your C compiler is actually a C++ compiler)